# Solar panels that also work at night?

Tags: solar-cells

This was first proposed in [a scientific study from 2019](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5089783). Essentially, the idea is that the solar cell generates power from the heat it radiates at night. That study claimed a theoretical maximum efficiency of 4 watts/m2. [A study released a few months ago](https://doi.org/10.1021/acsphotonics.9b00679) claimed that it could instead generate up to 50 watts/m^2. The basic concept is apparently known as a thermoradiative cell, and has been described in other scientific studies like [this](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep34837) and [this](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:46118928).

[image]

(Image taken from the second study)

The second study has received quite a lot of attention in articles like [this one](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/a30753326/reverse-solar-panels/).

However, I haven't found any questions about this here. Is this actually a practical idea? Could this really compensate for the traditional weakness of solar power?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/338113/why-does-the-earth-cool-at-night-time

Comment: That's an interesting question, but it (and its answers) don't really answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand a few concepts from the ACS paper. The paper says "We find that an ideal TR
cell at 300 K coupled with a 3 K radiating body (deep space)
has a maximum power output of 54 W/m2". I might be wrong because I just skimmed through the paper, but I did not come across parts where gradual cooling of the solar cell brings the cell to a state lot lesser than 300 K and hence, might bring down the power generated drastically.